# Infinite function call, Recursion or Timer?

Tags: java, web-services, recursion, timeout

I'm working on a **Java** function that should be called **infinitely**. This function will call a **web service** that will **return** back results. Results are then **parsed** and **analysed**.

The function ***should not be called again*** until the web service returns results, and these results are **analysed**.

Should I be using infinite recursion to achieve this? Or should I be using a timer that calls the function on certain intervals?

Some questions arise as well:

1. What happens if the web service's response times out? How can I prevent the application from crashing or making unlimited calls with no response?
2. Should I be creating an event driven class to handle these requests?
3. In terms of optimization, which of the solutions is more efficient?

-- Edit

I understand the question is a bit vague and general, so non detailed answers will do just fine, I'll focus on the implementation. I just need an advice on the approach. :)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Should I be using infinite recursion to achieve this?" - famous last words.

Comment: What about recursion depth problems in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost certainly *should not* use recursion for a process that doesn't have a definite "base case".  Infinite recursion is a horribly bad idea.  Each call eats up more and more of your stack, and eventually you'll die with an OOM error (or stack overflow, if Java differentiates between the two).

You could try something like

```
private Object mutex = new Object();
private boolean yourTaskIsRunning = false;

protected void yourTask()
{
    synchronized(mutex)
    {
        if (yourTaskIsRunning) return;
        yourTaskIsRunning = true;
    }
    try
    {
        // do your thing
    }
    finally
    {
        yourTaskIsRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Or, if you can bundle your task into a distinct object, use its being null or not as the "task is running" flag.  Create the object in the first `synchronized` section, start it in the "do your thing" section, and set it to null in the `finally` block.  (Note, either way, you'll need to ensure that all non-fatal paths through the function -- even thrown exceptions! -- "clear the flag" when they're done.  Hence the `finally` block.)

Either way, you can set up a timer to call this function, and it'll immediately return if it's already running.  The only drawback with the timer approach is that there might be some downtime between when one call ends and the next begins.

Comment: Interesting, synchronized statements seems to be a good idea. Would this prevent function call overlapping?

Comment: The `synchronized` block has one big purpose here: it keeps two *simultaneous* calls to the function from both succeeding (since only one can hold the lock at a time).  The first call will start running, and the second will be blocked til after the first has already started (and set the flag appropriately).  It'll see the flag set, know the function's already in use, and return immediately.  Secondly, it does some cache magic to ensure that other threads that call the function see the real value of the flag (as opposed to an old copy they may have cached earlier).

Answer (score 0):

I am confused. Why would you need a timer?

Seems like the calls are synchronous i.e. the next one does not fire until you receive the response from the first one.

Why not just a simple while loop with a try/catch block catching the java.net.SocketTimeoutException and breaking out of the loop on certain number of failures?

Recursion as suggested seems like a bad idea for this use case.